# How to create a streamable XSLT transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt, streaming, transformation, saxon

I would like to transform xml files in below structure to another one pretty similar to this, let's say each element name changes (ie A..F -> ANew..FNew). I would like to do it in streamable mode introduced by XSLT 3.0 using Saxon-EE v9.7 since I need to process very big files. Although I can partially succeed it (Root/Head section), I could not come up with a solution totally address the whole document since I cannot meet streamability rules Saxon-EE applies and I am lost among them... I appreciate any xslt suggestion that would work in streaming mode with Saxon-EE v9.7.

```
 <Root>
  <Head>
    <A/>
    <B/>
  </Head>
  <Grp>
     <D/>
     <E/>
     <SubGrp>
        <E/>
        <F/>
     </SubGrp>
     <SubGrp>
        <E/>
        <F/>
     </SubGrp>
  </Grp>
  <Grp>
     <D/>
     <E/>
     <SubGrp>
        <E/>
        <F/>
     </SubGrp>
     <SubGrp>
        <E/>
        <F/>
     </SubGrp>
  </Grp>
 </Root>
```

Comment: I appreciate that it can be quite tricky to get streaming transformations working. But the best way to proceed within the SO format is for you to show us an attempt that fails in a well-defined and reproduceable way, and then we can help you get over that specific obstacle. Note also that if you have purchased a Saxon-EE license then you have a direct support route to Saxonica: we don't mind you using StackOverflow, but if you use Saxonica's own support channel then we work hard to track problems through to a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
<xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

as the starting point then, if all you need is renaming some elements, you can then add templates doing that e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="A">
  <ANew>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ANew>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="F">
  <FNew>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </FNew>
</xsl:template>
```

If you still have problems then show us your XSLT together with the exact error message Saxon gives you.